# Recommendations AI to Big Query : Cloud Function gives timeout exception

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-recommendation

I am trying to get the predicted results from the Recommendations AI and store those predictions back into the big query.
After fetching a few rows, the Cloud Function gives timeout exception. Is there any way I can increase the timeout of Cloud Function? or if I can push the predicted results directly to the Big Query without any interaction of Cloud Function?

Comment: At max the time can be increased to 9 mins but Is there any way I can increase timeout more than that?

Comment: Posted an answer, Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57078459/15774176):

> The maximum run time of 540 seconds applies to all Cloud Functions, no
> matter how they're triggered. If you want to run something longer you
> will have to either chop it into multiple parts, or run it on a
> different platform, such as Compute Engine or App Engine.

Default timeout time can be changed [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list).

```
Follow this : select function >test function > edit > timeout
```

If you want to directly load your data to the BigQuery, you can follow this [blog](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/google-bigquery-the/9781492044451/ch04.html).

you can also look for the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/predictions/bigquery-export) on  export prediction data to BigQuery as this is not the recommended method you can go for [Remote Config personalization](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/personalization).

For more information related to BigQuery ML support model you can refer to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58445563/15774176) and [blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-do-online-prediction-with-bigquery-ml-db2248c0ae5).